# Errors in running a .sh file using Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, terminal

I followed a youtube video regarding *adding numbers*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOYYzikLGoY

He creates a .sh file using *vim* in terminal, this is the code:

```
read num1
read num2
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2`
echo $sum
```

I did the same, and saved the file in /home/dell ('dell' is name of user). When it is executed using **./addNumbers.sh** command in terminal, it gets executed perfectly - asks for two numbers, and outputs the result.

Now, I want to run the same thing, but in Eclipse. The code in java is:

```
package opening_prog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class opening_prog
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
String command[]= {"/home/dell./addNumbers.sh"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command); //process builder is ready with the environment
for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j<=5; j++){
        Process p = pb.start(); //process instance variable, throws declaration
                                //instantiation, and running
                                //starts a new process, which is the path to process builder, the shell code
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream(); //code has already started but waiting for values
                                                //pipe connected to output stream
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os); //connects the input to the shell with the java OutputStream

        ps.println(Integer.toString(i));
        ps.flush();//buffer so flush it again
        ps.println(Integer.toString(j));
        ps.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        //reader ready, now just to output
        String cOutput;

        while((cOutput=br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Sum of "+i+" & "+j+" is "+cOutput);
        }

    }
}
}
}
```

The output I am supposed to get is: **Sum of 1 & 1 is 2** and etc.
But instead I am getting errors, such as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home          /dell./addNumbers.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at opening_prog.opening_prog.main(opening_prog.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 1 more
```

May I know what is the problem. I would like to launch .launch files for my ROS project via a GUI made in Eclipse, and this is the first step I want to execute, but I am getting errors.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
the problem is solved, I wrote the *"command"* wrong. It should be **/home/dell/addNumbers.sh**, instead of /home/dell./addNumbers.sh

Comment: What are you going to do with `"/home/dell./addNumbers.sh"`?

Comment: for now I just want to run the file, and test what the guy achieved in the video.

Comment: I mean you got a typo! You need `"/home/dell/addNumbers.sh"`!

Comment: ohh.
thanks for correcting that. I thought I have to put **./** in order to run the .sh file. Thanks a lot. Appreciate that.